# Angular Multi component Page Design

Tags: angular6, angular-components, angular-module

**Technology Stack :**

Angular 6

Angular Material

I am working on an a Single Page Application in `Angular 6 and Angular material` which has only one `PAGE`.

The page has three sections apart from header and footer as  :

Search Section 
Download Section 
List student record section

I want to make the Angular application as modular and hence decided to use below three components to represent three sections :

SearchComponent 
StudentRecordComponent 
DownloadComponent

My question is :

These individual components will have its **OWN HTML** and the **final PAGE** will have references to all these components. (index.html will bootstrap the root component )

Means , every section of the page will come from **INDIVIDUAL COMPONENTS .** 
Is my design correct with respect to this ?

More specifically , pseudo code for the HTML for the page is given below as a **template for root component** (`app.component.html`)

**Root Component Template** should contain reference to all these components.

So typical implementation would be  :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl : './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

whereas **app.component.html** will have below mark up.

```
 <div id="mainDiv">

 <div>
    <search-component></search-component> <!-- Search component HTML --> 
 </div>

 <div>
    <download-component></download-component> <!-- Download component HTML --> 
 </div> 

 <div>
    <StudentRecordComponent></StudentRecordComponent>  <!-- Student Record component HTML --> 
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There should not be any issues with this implementation.

Comment: I have updated question a bit . Can you take a look please  ?

Comment: looks fine to me. It should work. Take notes if you want want certain components to share the same data in which case, you'll need to read up on component interaction and also if you want states managed globally within your app then i suggest reading up on ngrx early and setting it up before your app gets cluttered down the line